# Made a form that e-mails content, but It looks horrible in an email. Need to make file upload compatible

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I'm having trouble making my e-mail look better, such as with CSS because it looks like plain text:
[image]

Is there anyway to bold or something with html? I've tried concat with `<b>` tags but I don't think it works because I'm assigning a variable. How can I make it look better? I'm using WordPress.

Also how can I make it File Upload compatible? Thanks

Here's (part) of my code:

```
<?php

$message = "You have received a message from " . $fullname . ", See information below:" . "\n" .
"\n\n" . "General:" . "\n" .
"\nFull Name: " . $fullname . "\n" .
"\nEmail Address: " . $email . "\n" .
"\nSubject: " . $Subject . "\n" .
"\nIssue Type: " . $issuetype . "\n" .
"\n\n" . "Hardware:" . "\n" .
"\nOrder Number: " . $ordernumber . "\n" .
"\nOrder Date: " . $orderdate . "\n" .
"\nPhoto: " . $photo;


//php mailer variables
$to = get_option('admin_email');
$subject = "Customer Support Form Subject: " . $Subject . " By " . $fullname;
$headers = 'From: '. $email
?>

<?php 
if($_POST["submit"]){
  $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/ is a good start but ultimately you might be interested in a library such as [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=tutorial). I use PHPMailer and am grateful everyday that I continue to use it.

Comment: What kind of stuff would PHPMailer allow me to do? And why is it better to exactly?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're using wordpress and using wp_mail to send the email. The default content-type based on the [wordpress codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail)
is text/plain. with that said you won't be able to add styling to it unless you change the content type to text/html using wp_mail_content_type filter or add it to your $headers variable.

Notice that I changed the `\n` to `<br />` and added additional header (`$headers = 'Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8' . '\r\n';`) to set the content type.

```
<?php

$message = "You have received a message from " . $fullname . ", See information below:" . "<br />" .
"<br /><br /><strong>" . "General:" . "<strong><br />" .
"<br /><strong>Full Name:</strong> " . $fullname . "<br />" .
"<br /><strong>Email Address: </strong> " . $email . "<br />" .
"<br /><strong>Subject: </strong>" . $Subject . "<br />" .
"<br /><strong>Issue Type:</strong> " . $issuetype . "<br />" .
"<br /><br />" . "Hardware:" . "<br />" .
"<br /><strong>Order Number: </strong>" . $ordernumber . "<br />" .
"<br /><strong>Order Date:</strong> " . $orderdate . "<br />" .
"<br />Photo: " . $photo;


//php mailer variables
$to = get_option('admin_email');
$subject = "Customer Support Form Subject: " . $Subject . " By " . $fullname;
$headers = 'Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8' . '\r\n';
$headers .= 'From: '. $email . '\r\n';
?>

<?php 
if($_POST["submit"]){
  $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

Regarding adding attachments please check this post.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50264/using-wp-mail-with-attachments-but-no-attachments-received